# Iterating over a java.util.Set inside <p:dataGrid>. causes, The class org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet doesn't have the property xxx

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, eclipselink

I have three tables in MySQL database.

- category
- sub_category
- product

The relationship between these tables is intuitive - one-to-many in the order in which they appear.

---

I'm getting a `List<SubCategory>` from MySQL database in which there is a `java.util.Set<Product>` for each sub category as obvious.

I'm iterating over `List<SubCategory>` in `<p:dataGrid>` as follows.

```
<p:dataGrid id="dataGrid" rows="4" first="0" columns="1" value="#{productDetailsManagedBean}" var="row" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" pageLinks="10" lazy="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="1,2,3">

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.subCatId}"/>

            <p:carousel id="carousel" value="#{row.productSet}" var="prodRow" numVisible="4" headerText="#{row.subCatName}">
                <h:outputText value="#{prodRow.prodId}"/>
            </p:carousel>

        </h:panelGrid>

</p:dataGrid>
```

The value attribute of `<p:carousel>` doesn't function. It just says, `{IndirectSet: not instantiated}`. Hence, accessing any product using EL like `#{prodRow.prodId}` as seen with `<h:outputText>` will throw an exception like,

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet' does not have the property 'prodId'
```

When I change,

```
<h:outputText value="#{prodRow.prodId}"/>
```

to

```
<h:outputText value="#{row.productSet.size()}"/>
```

It correctly shows the size of `row.productSet` (it is not empty, the size is exactly the same as the number of rows for each sub category in `List<SubCategory>`. The `Set` is precisely initialized).

Why does it throw an exception while accessing a property of `Product` like `#{prodRow.prodId}`?

How to solve this problem?

This is something explained precisely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8301820/1391249) but I couldn't solve the same problem in this particular situation.

<sub>I'm using JPA provided by EclipseLink 2.3.2</sub>

Comment: Looks like PrimeFaces' Carousel doesn't like Set. Have you tried with a List instead?

Comment: {IndirectSet: not instantiated} means your method is calling toString on the Set.  IndirectSet returns this string instead of the underlying Set implementation when it hasn't been triggered yet, and has nothing to do with your problem other than shows that the p:carousel isn't doing what you think it should with a Set.  Make the relationship Eager to remove Eclipselink's use of IndirectSet to see what happens

Comment: @Chris : `FetchType.EAGER` did not work either. I have now changed `Set` to `List` everywhere and it works just fine, no need to use `.toArray()` as shown in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22545078/1391249).

Comment: Great.  The suggestion to use eager wasnt a solution; it was just to allow you to verify the problem wasn't with indirectset, but all sets.  Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried changing `java.util.Set` to `java.util.List` but doing so requires too many changes to the application which is a pain.

Instead, I have turned `java.util.Set` into an array using its `toArray()` method and it worked.

```
<p:carousel id="carousel" value="#{row.productSet.toArray()}" var="prodRow" numVisible="6" headerText="#{row.subCatName}">
    <!--<h:outputText value="#{prodRow.prodId}"/>-->
    <p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" name="product_image/medium/#{prodRow.productImageSet.toArray()[0].prodImage}" alt="#{prodRow.prodName}" height="140" width="135"/>
</p:carousel>
```

I have replaced `<h:outputText>` with `<p:graphicImage>` for a concrete requirement for displaying images on `<p:graphicImage>`.

<sub>I don't know whether the problem has to do with the JPA provider EclipseLink itself or `java.util.Set`. If someone knows, please clarify.</sub>

---

**EDIT:**

I have now changed every inverse (or mapped by) field from `java.util.Set` to `java.util.List` everywhere in my application and it works just fine. There is no need to use `.toArray()` as have to be used with `java.util.Set`.

Comment: Make the relationship Eager to remove Eclipselink's use of IndirectSet to see what happens