# Collections.sort doesn't invoke in java 8

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, java-8, eclipselink

I have EJB facade generated by NetBeans and sorting collections in entities fetched by JPA doesn't work. Here is the code:

```java
@Stateless
public class CompetitionFacade extends AbstractFacade<Competition> implements CompetitionFacadeLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mot_persistence_unit")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public CompetitionFacade() {
    super(Competition.class);
}

@Override
public Competition findAndInitializeGD(Integer idCompetition) {
    Competition entity = em.find(Competition.class, idCompetition);

    entity.getGroupDetailsList().forEach(p -> System.out.println("First lambda " + p.getIdGroupName()));
    new ArrayList<>(entity.getGroupDetailsList()).forEach(p -> System.out.println("Second lambda " + p.getIdGroupName()));

    Collections.sort(entity.getGroupDetailsList(), new Comparator<GroupDetails>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(GroupDetails o1, GroupDetails o2) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("First sorting");
        }

    });

    Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(entity.getGroupDetailsList()), new Comparator<GroupDetails>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(GroupDetails o1, GroupDetails o2) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Second sorting");
        }

    });

    return entity;
}

}
```

AbstractFacade:

```java
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

// auto-generated methods like find/edit etc.
}
```

Invoking this method gives this exception:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Second sorting
```

Why isn't first exception thrown from sorting? Also it looks like lambda expression doesn't work either. After adding these two lines

```java
entity.getGroupDetailsList().forEach(p -> System.out.println("First lambda " + p.getIdGroupName()));
new ArrayList<>(entity.getGroupDetailsList()).forEach(p -> System.out.println("Second lambda " + p.getIdGroupName()));
```

output is

```java
Info:   Second lambda entities.GroupName[ idGroupName=709 ]
Info:   Second lambda entities.GroupName[ idGroupName=706 ]
Info:   Second lambda entities.GroupName[ idGroupName=707 ]
Info:   Second lambda entities.GroupName[ idGroupName=708 ]
```

EDIT:

This is field from the entity

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "competition")
private List<GroupDetails> groupDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

with normal getter

```java
public List<GroupDetails> getGroupDetailsList() {
    return groupDetailsList;
}
```

EDIT2:
I found satisfying answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27980037/3803447 after accepted answer which hinted me right way.

Comment: What does `getGroupDetailsList` return? And is it modifyable?

Comment: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "competition")
    private List<GroupDetails> groupDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();`

and getter:
`public List<GroupDetails> getGroupDetailsList() {
        return groupDetailsList;
    }`

 and yes, it is modifyable. I can add new elements to the list.

Comment: Please edit the question to include that additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lazy loading enabled (which is the default), then the Collection returned by `getGroupDetailsList` is actually a special wrapper class provided by your JPA provider to act a middle-man for fetching the collection once you access it.  Try debugging and seeing what class is actually returned.

Comment: You are right, the returned list is a class of `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList`. Can I change somehow this behavior with EclipseLink?

Comment: The way you're doing it in the second sort is the way to do it, rewrapping it in an ArrayList.

Comment: Accepted your answer because it helped me find the right answer.

Comment: thank you!  Glad I could help. :)