# How can I use Java Stream API on JPA Objects?

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, java-stream, eclipselink

I have a List like

```
@OneToMany
private List<Personal> personal;
```

Later on I want to filter results

```
List<Integer> ist = personal.stream().map(p -> p.getPnr()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I always get an empty list. When I create an old school for-loop, things work as expected. 
I added `fetch=FETCH_TYPE.EAGER` to the `@OneToMany` annotation, but it didn't fix the problem.

The debugger says, at runtime, 'personal' is a 'indirect list'. Is this the problem? And what can I do to fix it?

---

Code that work fine

```
List<Integer> ist = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (Personal p : personal) 
   ist.add(p.getPnr());
```

Comment: Can you share your *old school for-loop*

Comment: Can you try copying the contents of the `personal` list to another new list e.g: `List<Personal> list = new ArrayList(personal)` and then attempt to stream?

Comment: Are you using excel

Comment: List<Integer> ist = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Personal p : personal)
    ist.add(p.getPnr());

Comment: Also I assume you're using EclipseLink?

Comment: What is the class of the list object assigned to `personal`?  The problem could be that that class doesn't implement `stream()`  properly.

Comment: At least it works this way:

List<Integer> ist = new ArrayList<>(personal).stream().map(p -> p.getPnr()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: yes, I'm using EclipseLink

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362581/stream-api-not-working-for-lazy-loaded-collections-in-eclipselink-glassfish) help maybe?

Comment: See [stream on JPA lazy list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37925649/2711488)

Comment: @JoopEggen since streams do not allow to modify the source collection, `Collections.unmodifiableList(list).stream()` will simply delegate to `list.stream()`

Comment: @Holger the link of **michalk** poinst to some bugs in eclipseLink with as workaround wrapping the list in an `unmodifiableList`. Which is better than a `new ArrayList(list)`

Comment: @JoopEggen his workaround is `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(domains))`, which works due to the copying operation. The `unmodifiableList` does not contribute to the work-around but only makes the list unmodifiable, which was already present in the question's code. When you omit the copying into an `ArrayList`, you omitted the actual workaround.

Comment: @Holger I am getting dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what the actuall problem is, but creating a new List works for me:

```
List<Integer> ist = new ArrayList<>(personal).stream().map(p -> p.getPnr()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: One of the comments should have pointed you to EclipseLink bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446236#c12 which is fixed in the 2.7 stream.