# Create a Class That extends Java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create class that extends the `java.util.ArrayList` by overriding
the add method in the following way: it does nothing if the object to be added already exists
in the collection; otherwise it calls the add method in the super class to add the object into
the collection.

My code look like that so far but it gives a `NullPointerException`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public ArrayList<E> mylist;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (!mylist.contains(e)) {
            super.add(e);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myArrayList<Integer> listing = new myArrayList<Integer>();
        listing.add(4);
        listing.add(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < listing.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listing.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should provide the entire error message? Exactly where did the null pointer come from?

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of `myList`. You should be using `this`, as in `if( ! this.contains( e ) )`

Comment: Java conventions for a class name require class names to begin with an uppercase letter. So `MyArrayList`, not `MyArrayList`.

Comment: So you use inheritance & composition? This won't work.

Comment: why reinventing the loop? You can use hashset

Comment: @JohannesKuhn is right. `extends ArrayList<E>` is *inheritance* (what you said you want). `public ArrayList<E> mylist;` is *composition*. Don’t do both.

Comment: If you want to see what can go wrong if you do both, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367413/845414). Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we can't be sure this is your problem (unless you show us the stacktrace!), it looks like an NPE is likely to occur in this line:

```
    if (!mylist.contains(e)) {
```

because `mylist` is never initialized.

In fact, if you are trying to extend `ArrayList` rather than create a list wrapper, the `mylist` variable should not exist at all.  The list state is in the superclasses private variables.  Instead, the `add` method should probably be written like this:

```
@Override
public boolean add(E e) {
    if (!super.contains(e)) {
        return super.add(e);  // See note
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: in general, you should return whatever the superclass returns here.  However, when the superclass is `ArrayList`, we know<sup>1</sup> that `add` will return `true`, so this is only "saving" a line of code.  There *might* be marginal performance difference, depending on how smart the JIT optimizer is.

<sup>1 - We know because the `ArrayList.add` javadoc specifically states that `true` is returned.</sup>

---

But this looks like you are trying to create a "set-like" list class.  There could be better alternatives; e.g. `LinkedHashSet` has a defined iteration order, and addition is `O(1)` rather than `O(N)`.  (Admittedly, `LinkedHashSet` uses a lot more memory, and it has no efficient equivalent to the positional `List.get(int)` method.)

Answer (score 1):

You got a `NullPointerException` on this line `if (!mylist.contains(e)) {` because `myList` is not instanciated in the default constructor.

```
public MyArrayList() {
 this.myList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But.. you mix inheritance and composition here...

That means `add` will be applied to `myList` and `get(index)` will be applied on `this`.. So you actually maintain 2 lists here..

In you example `myList.contains` will always return `false` because you never add something into. this -> `super.add(e)` is the same than `this.add(e)` and it is a different instance of list.

So just removed `myList` instance field and replace your `add` like this :

```
  @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (!contains(e)) {
            add(e);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Watch out that this class is not `thread-safe`.  Here there is a `check-then-act` race condition (check = contains(), act = add())

Finally `List` are designed to allow duplicates... if you don't want duplicates.. just use a `Set`

Comment: It is also not thread-safe because `ArrayList` (the superclass) is not thread-safe.