# Java 8 stream.collect(Collectors.grouppingBy()) returns map of size 0 when used on a JPA obtained list/object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following class structure

```
public enum RPAttributeStatus {
    NOT_CREATED,
    UPDATED
}

public class RPAttribute{
    private int id;
    private RPAttributeStatus status;
}


public class RP{
    private int id;
    private List<RPAttribute> listOfRPAttributes;
}

//with getters and setters
```

After i get the RP object I want to obtain a map with the key as the `RPAttributeStatus` and the value should be a `List<RPAttribute>`

I am getting the object from a JPA Dao:

```
RiskProfileDao riskProfileDao = new RiskProfileDao();
RiskProfile riskProfile = riskProfileDao.findById(id);
```

And I'm trying to obtain the map as follows:

```
riskProfile.getRPAttributes().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RPAttribute::getStatus));
```

But I always get a map of size 0 but the `RP` object contains a populated list of `RPAttributes` that are not null, and have a status.

Comment: What do you do with the result of the `collect()` operation? Please show that part of your code too.

Comment: Weird. Interesting. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: @Thomas it doesn't matter what I want to do with the map. The problem is that the map is empty... and it shouldnt't be

Comment: @Ole I don't think it matters because the only part that is missing is the part that involves the creation of the objects... but I will update it if you want

Comment: What kind of `List` is your source? If it’s a JPA lazy list or similar anti-pattern implementation, you may be a victim of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26841569/2711488).

Comment: @Holger Indeed it is a JPA list, but I went on and debugged it and it contains the elements and the statuses before trying to create the map... but I think it might be something related to what you're saying

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37925649/2711488). It might appear populated, because the overridden methods tell you so, but the superclass’ internal state is still that of an empty list.

Comment: @Holger thank you very much, that was the problem. I am using eclipseLink which uses the JPA 2.1 Reference Implementation instead of 2.7 that solved the problem mentioned in your previous link which is also my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot reproduce. I added constructors and getters and ran this piece of code:

```
    RP riskProfile = new RP(7, Arrays.asList(new RPAttribute(1, RPAttributeStatus.UPDATED), 
            new RPAttribute(2, RPAttributeStatus.NOT_CREATED)));
    Map<RPAttributeStatus, List<RPAttribute>> m
            = riskProfile.getRPAttributes().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RPAttribute::getStatus));
    System.out.println("Size " + m.size());
```

It prints;

```
Size 2
```

It seems to me your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I somehow erased the part in which I obtain the object from a JPA DAO. The answer is what @Holger said in his comments