# Java 8 Stream Filter returning an empty list always

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to filter all the transfers for which the signedOn field is null. When I run the first piece of code it's clear which ones are null and which ones are not and they're logged correctly, but when I run the stream filter it returns an empty list and I can't seem to find what's the problem with it... signedOn is a Date field.

This works and logs all wether the entries are null or not:

```
    for (Transfer transfer : route.getTransferCollection()) {
        if (transfer.getSignedOn() == null) {
            logInfo("This transfer is null");
        } else if (transfer.getSignedOn() != null) {
            logInfo("This transfer is not null");
        }
    }
```

This returns an empty list:

```
    return route.getTransferCollection()
            .stream()
            .filter(transfer -> transfer.getSignedOn() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: what is the return type of `getTransferCollection()`?

Comment: How about a log statement inside `filter`?

Comment: @Harald it's a Collection<Transfer>

Comment: @Eugene how do I do a log inside the filter?? I tried without the filter statement and it still returns me an empty list

Comment: You say “I want to filter”, but your original loop doesn’t filter, all it does is logging. Then, you write a stream operation that returns a `List`, but your your original loop doesn’t produce a list. So these operation are not equivalent and do not match your description about what you want to do. When you start writing code without knowing what you actually want, the result will rarely be what you want. Or perhaps it is, but you don’t know it.

Comment: `1` your initial list is empty OR `2` there are no `signedOn` null values, so after filtering you will have empt list

Comment: @Holger the first code was not supposed to filter, it was supposed to log! Because my stream was not doing anything, just returning null values, so I made a simple way to test that the list was not empty, it logs once for each member inside the List! It was just to tell that I know the list is not empty and the problem is just inside the stream...

Comment: I see. So logging via `peek` could reveal whether there is a fundamental difference between looping via `for` and iterating via a `Stream`. If so, check, whether [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37925649/2711488) applies in your case.

Comment: @Holger updated both - what a great late night read that was!

Comment: @Holger it was exactly this you suggested in the comment, I never thought it'd be related to JPA but well, what do you know? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Hello @Holger for some reason this post is trending and has at least 4x more views than the duplicate one. How can I reopen it to ellaborate a better answer here for people who're looking?

Answer (score 2):

You can log your statements inside the `filter` itself

```
 return route.getTransferCollection()
        .stream()
        .filter(transfer -> {
                boolean test = transfer.getSignedOn() == null;
                if(test){
                   // log wathever
                } else {
                   // log diff
                }
                return test
               })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use `peek` to log inside streams btw, but using it in your case would require to test against null twice.

You can also use a different collector may be to get the ones that are null and the ones that are not (without `filter`):

```
.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(transfer -> transfer.getSignedOn() == null))
```

Comment: I tried it exactly like this but it doesn't log anything at all :/ I have no idea what's going on so I substituted it for smth pretty primitive such as a for that adds to another list when it's null because It's sunday and I wanna go home

Comment: @brightpants thats really weird, but without seeing your entirr code, its hard to tell what is going on. U might be able to see exactly what is going on tomorrow with a fresh mind ( reviewing your code is always good IMO)

Comment: There are two possibilities for the result being empty: `route.getTransferCollection()` is empty already, or all transfers have a signedOnDate (Note that filter defines which elements to keep, not which ones to remove). Maybe you could log the size of `route.getTransferCollection()` before the stream to see whether it is empty.

Comment: Stream<>.peek(): API note: This method exists mainly to support debugging

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if `route.getTransferCollection()` is already an empty List. Please try checking like this:

```
route.getTransferCollection()
    .stream()
    .forEach(System.out::println);  // or .forEach(e -> logInfo(e));
```

and see whether this will print anything.

Comment: In this example, it will definitely not print anything.  You don't have a terminal operation on your stream.

Comment: My bad, changed `peek` to `forEach`. Thank you, @Brian Goetz!