# Spring repository find calls in java parallelStream return empty during unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, java-stream

Spring repository find calls inside java parallelStream **for unit tests** do not return the expected results. They return empty/no results. I suspect it could be some configuration needed for spring tests when using parallelStream? Any ideas?

```
//Is never empty
List<ObjectHistory> allHist = objectHistoryRepository.findAll();

//problematic
objects.parallelStream()
        .forEach(i-> {
              //Is  empty except for one or none
              List<ObjectHistory> allHist = objectHistoryRepository.findAll();

              //Optional is empty except for one or none
              Optional<ObjectHistory> objHistoryOptional = objectHistoryRepository.findFirstById(i.getId());
         });

//works fine
objects.stream()
        .forEach(i-> {
              //Is never empty
              List<ObjectHistory> allHist = objectHistoryRepository.findAll();

              //Optional is never empty
              Optional<ObjectHistory> objHistoryOptional = objectHistoryRepository.findFirstById(i.getId());
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide a whole unit test?

Comment: @RoninDev The code above is part of the tested code, not the unit test itself. The problem with the parallelStream appears only when executed through the unit tests. I am sorry I cannot share a whole unit test but what it does is adding data to the repos and then execute the function that includes the code from my question.

Comment: The unti tests in spring have @Transactional behavior on test. May be it affect you. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing. I asked about unit test to see your assertions statements because it can make sense. Also interest in annotations on test class

Comment: @Holger I updated the title. I hope the problem is clear now. You can see also the comments in the code to understand the different behavior.

Comment: The code comments were not helpful as they did not clarify what was expected behavior and what unintended actual behavior. The issue reminds me of the [stream on JPA lazy list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37925649/2711488) issue.

Comment: Looks like @RoninDev pointed me in the right direction. I was using javax @ Transactional and @ Before annotations. Changed to spring @ Transactional using also the @ Before/After Transaction and then everything is fine. Still don't understand why the normal stream() had different behavior in the first place.